# Как сделать перегрузку оператора?

Tags: c++, строки, перегрузка-операторов

Всем привет! Есть класс в котором создается массив строк. Как перезагрузить оператор `+`, так чтобы можно было создать массив строк из текущего массива строк `+` другой массив? Типа как в python метод `extend`. Вообще можно ли такое сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Strings{
  private:
  int count_strings;
  
  public:
  vector <string> strs;
  
  Strings(int);
  string get_str(int); // получение строки из массива
  void fill_array(); // заполнение массива
  void print(); // вывод на экран
};

Strings::Strings(int count_strings){
    this->count_strings = count_strings;
}

void Strings::fill_array(){
    for (int i=0;i<this->count_strings;i++){
        char * t = new char(50);
        cout << "String " << i << ": ";
        cin >> t;
        this->strs.push_back(t);
    }
}

void Strings::print(){
    for (int i=0;i<this->count_strings;i++){
        cout << this->strs[i] << endl;
    }
}

string Strings::get_str(int index){
    if (index > this->count_strings){
        return "Вы вышли за пределы массива";
    }
    
    return this->strs[index];
}

int main(){
    Strings obj(3);
    obj.fill_array();
    obj.print();
    
    string buffer = obj.get_str(2);
    cout << buffer << endl;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да запросто. Только вот мне ваш подход не нравится - например, зачем это поле с количеством строк? которое известно - оно равно количеству строк в векторе...

Или считывание не строк, а слов, длиной не более 50... Возврат строки при выходе за пределы массива строк - а вдруг именно такая строка и хранится в массиве? А вот исключения, генерируемые функцией `at()` - это вполне однозначное указание на выход индекса за пределы массива.

Словом, я немного переделал ваш код, добавив тот самый оператор.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Strings{
    vector <string> strs;
public:
    Strings() {};
    string get_str(int) const;  // получение строки из массива
    void fill_array(int count); // заполнение массива
    void print() const;         // вывод на экран

    Strings operator+(const Strings&s) const;
};

void Strings::fill_array(int count)
{
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        string s;
        cout << "String " << i << ": ";
        getline(cin,s);
        strs.push_back(s);
    }
}

void Strings::print() const
{
    for (int i=0;i<strs.size();i++)
    {
        cout << strs[i] << endl;
    }
}

string Strings::get_str(int index) const
{
    return strs.at(index);
}

Strings Strings::operator+(const Strings&s) const
{
    Strings r;
    r.strs = strs;
    r.strs.insert(r.strs.end(),s.strs.begin(),s.strs.end());
    return r;
}


int main()
{
    Strings obj;
    obj.fill_array(3);
    obj.print();

    Strings n;
    n = obj + obj;
    n.print();

    string buffer = obj.get_str(2);
    cout << buffer << endl;

}
```

Comment: `Да запросто. Только вот мне ваш подход не нравится - например, зачем это поле с количеством строк? которое известно - оно равно количеству строк в векторе...`  ну типа чтобы знать сколько строк в массиве будет, типа до куда циклу работать

Comment: А такой вопрос: для чего вы ставите `const` в методе, после `(...)`

Comment: А если вы потом захотите добавить пару строк? А так вы указываете это количество в функции заполнения, что логичнее. И вообще, у вас получается несогласованность - между созданием объекта и его заполнением количество строк в векторе (нулевое) не соответствует вашему полю... `const` добавляется, потому что эти функции не меняют состояния объекта и могут работать с константными объектами (без этого добавления они с константными объектами вызваны быть не могут).